# Slotted Optical Switch (OPB992T51Z) anode and cathode connections?

Tags: led, switches

I have an optek [Photologic® Slotted Optical Switch](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/414/OPB960-990_SERIES-23547.pdf).  It is meant to turn off when the near infrared emissions (850 - 940nm) are blocked.

It has five wires as follows:

[image]

I am unsure about what to do with the anode and cathode, (most likely connect the anode to Vcc).

Firstly, I connected Vcc and GND but the signal voltage did not change when the LED was blocked.

Next I connected the anode to Vcc and the cathode to GND Aas shown below and retried.

[image]
Still nothing.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Not to Vcc directly but to Vcc through a biasing resistor to meet the "input diode" specifications.

Comment: You probably have blown the LED already with that connection; better try another device, this time with a several hundred ohm resistor between Anode and Vcc.

Comment: @EugeneSh. BobU, thanks guys will give it another go, with another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED should be powered via the Anode and Cathode pins, the same way any other LED is powered - with a series resistor to limit the LED current to a safe value.